# Joining results from different laboratories

Tags: data-visualization, bayes

I've done a large number of tests (100). I also have access to a thesis where it is reported the same type of tests on the same type of material. The mean and COV values are reported, along with the histograms.
I'd like to use this information, to join it with my data and from there do some model selection.
Since the number of tests done by previous researchers (80) is similar to what I did I think Bayesian Theory can only be useful if one of the series of results is considered representative of the (unknown) population. Maybe joining all the data makes more sense. Any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for advice on what exactly? I'm not sure I understand your question. You have used the *data-visualization* tag, is your goal simply to plot 180 tests somehow?

Comment: Yes, I can make a joint histogram with my data and the additional 80 tests histogram. My question is more related with how appropriate is that compared to apply Bayes? Also if I hadn't the histograms, just the mean ans sd, do you see any way of joining the tests w/o Bayes? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a big expert on Bayes, but to get a good answer from someone, we're going to need to know how appropriate a histogram vs Bayes is *for what*?

Comment: The main objective is to select a distribution for the data.

Comment: So you want to visualize the distribution of a test statistic (eg $t$) for 180 different tests? If so, a histogram seems fine. I'm not sure what any of that has to do w/ Bayes.

Comment: The histogram is needed to fit the distributions. The question is what are th things to look in choosing to fit distributions to the joint histogram or to fit distributions to each tests series and then use Bayes to update one of them.

Comment: Now I think we're getting closer. I gather that what you want is to come up with an appropriate prior distribution to use with future analyses by examining the empirical distribution of a large number of existing test statistics. That seems reasonable. If you use R, you might want to check out the [fitdistrplus](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html) package. You may also want to read a little about [meta-analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis).

Comment: Yes I'm using R and fitdist of fitdistrplus package! Excellent tool! do you have any comments on Bayes and meta-analysis? In some cases they can compete, because you can always use meta-analysis or decide that you have a good enough prior and just use Bayes to update it.

Comment: I'm not necessarily arguing that you should use meta-analysis instead of Bayes. Someone else who knows more about this is going to have to answer your questions, now that it's clear what they are. I just thought I'd throw out some suggestions.The suggestion may not even be useful. I only mention it because it's a subject that discusses how to determine things like the mean and variance of empirical results / test statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this aright, you plan to do some modelling.

- You have a prior belief, based on the published mean, cov, sd, and histograms from 80 samples
- You have your own data.

So, you can calculate whatever you want to calculate, assuming no knowledge at all of anything. But you have an alternative, that is a Bayesian analysis starts with the prior beliefs, and goes via the likelihood of the data, to whatever it is you plan to calculate. As you have only a little more data than the prior, you'll have to take it seriously.

To do this, you need to use something like jags or BUGS.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I proceed with the Bayesian analysis? since my data and the other data are similar in values and in size, I don't find easy to select a prior.

Comment: Choosing correct prior distributions given some prior information is, to my knowledge, still an unsolved problem. One way forward would be to pick the maximum entropy prior, which for a given mean and covariance, is a normal distribution (google maximum entropy distributions, or pick up a copy of E.T.Jaynes 'Probability Theory - The Logic of Science' for more info). However, the presence of the histogram complicates this a bit, as it certainly has useful extra information in it. I'm not sure how you can best incorporate that.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. If my prior is based on a smaller number of results than the new data how can I justify changing my distribution with that prior? This is even more important if my posterior is significantly changed by the prior. Both prior and new data can be unrepresentative and may even be better if grouped together rather than using Bayes.